# Consulta MySQL sin tener el nombre específico

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo una barra para buscar tareas. Todo funciona bien, lo que pasa es que quiero que, por ejemplo, si tengo una tarea llamada "123" y busco "12" la consulta me traiga el dato de "123".

Hasta ahora lo tengo así:

```
if (isset($_POST['buscar_tarea'])) {
    $tarea_buscar = $_POST['tarea_buscar'];
    $query = "SELECT title FROM task WHERE title = '$tarea_buscar'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conectarbd, $query);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $fila[0];
}
```

Cuando consulto una tarea con un nombre que no es totalmente igual me envía el dato de NULL

Comment: En lugar de = usa like  $tarea_buscar.'%' .

Comment: Me envia este error
`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\funciones\buscar.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\funciones\buscar.php(12): mysqli_fetch_array(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitacora\funciones\buscar.php on line 12`

Comment: Prueba el SELECT directamente, es decir, usando un valor concreto. Ejemplo: SELECT title FROM task WHERE title like '12%'  y comprueba que hay valores. En el código asegurate que las comillas están en el patrón del like.

Comment: Si me funciono muchas gracias, nose si quieras ponerlo como respuesta para ponerle que la respuesta es correcta, Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa **LIKE** en vez de **=**.
Con LIKE lo que haces es indicarle que vas a comparar el campo con un string que puede o no tener los caracteres antes o después.

Por ejemplo:

Si tu campo tiene `"juan orlando garcia"` y tú buscas `lando` te va devolverá la entrada, pero si buscas `l4ndo` no lo hará ya que `LIKE` solo te busca la palabra con caracteres antes `(%string)` o después`(string%)`.

La consulta MySQL es:

```
select * from task where title LIKE '%$tarea_buscar%';
```

Con esto te devolverá todas las entradas que tenga la palabra de la variable `$tarea_buscar` dentro del campo sin importar si hay caracteres antes o después.